# DELETE FROM query via CSV contents MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, sql-delete

I have a CSV file uploaded to the same directory as the file containing the email addresses of people I want to delete from a table (all at once) in my database. The code I'm using echoes correctly but doesn't delete anything from the table. The CSV file is uploaded to the same directory as the file containing the code below.

```
<?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("x", "x", "x") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("volunteers2012") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql);
    /********************************/

    $addresses = file('deleteEmails.csv');
    foreach($addresses as $address) {
        $safe_address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
        $sql = "DELETE FROM vols2012 WHERE `email` = '$safe_address'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    echo "DELETION A GREAT SUCCESS!";
    ?>
```

Round 2- Trying with a .txt file

```
<?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("x", "x", "x") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("volunteers2012") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql);
    /********************************/

    $addresses = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ('deleteEmails.txt')";
foreach($addresses as $address) {
$safe_address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$sql = "DELETE FROM vols2012 WHERE (email = '$safe_address')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   }
    echo "DELETION A GREAT SUCCESS!";
    ?>
```

I'm still getting the success echo, but with the error- Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`.

Comment: Is it a CSV file? Or just a list of email addresses?

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) supports CSV, so you don't need the PHP loop.

Comment: It's a CSV file with one column of email addresses...I don't have the email column labeled...trying that and the LOAD DATA now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up not using the upload to delete method and instead created an html page w/ checkboxes to delete by hand. In the end this was the best method as I needed to leave some of the records in one table but not the other.

```
          <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <?php


       // Delete the customer rows (only if the form has been submitted)

         if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
      foreach($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id) {

             $query="DELETE FROM volConfirm WHERE email='$delete_id'";


                mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in query: ' .mysql_errno() . mysql_error());
            }


        }


        // Display the customer rows with checkboxes for deleting
        $query="SELECT * FROM volConfirm";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['email'] .'"name="todelete[]" />';
        echo $row['agreeName'];
        echo ' '.$row['position'];
        echo ' '.$row['shift_times'];
        echo ' '.$row['email'];
        echo ' '.$row['confirmed'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';
       }
     ?>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" />
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a CSV list of email addresses, try this query on for size:

**PHP**

```
$emails = 'a@b.com,b@c.org,foo@example.org';
```

**SQL**

```
$emails = mysql_real_escape_string($emails);
$sql = "DELETE FROM vols2012 WHERE `email` IN ({$emails})";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: But where do I call the .csv file?

Comment: In the above example, I am simply assuming that the CSV file is is read via `fopen();` or `file_get_contents();`. I have just excluded it for brevity.

Comment: Ah- you assumed I knew how to do that? I'm flattered :) I do have a download php file that I think contains something similar. I'm not sure how to modify for row deletion. Would the file I'm using to delete need to contain all of the column headers?

Comment: Oh, hm. I assumed from the first example that the CSV file was actually in the format as specified in the `$emails` variable. In the end, there's no "set" way to do this, it all depends on what the source CSV file looks like, and what you want to do with it. Providing the CSV source may help get better answers.